# Display results of a SQL query with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have been provided a PS script which calls a simple SQL query, displays the results and plays a voice... supposedly. This is designed to go into a BI gadget which just displays a number from the PS script.

The correct count from the query is not displaying and is for some reason stuck on 2.

```
$sql = "<simple COUNT query>"

$items = invoke-sql -server "<server name>" -database "<db name>" -user "<uname>" -password "<password>" -sql $sql -timeout 180

$day = (get-date).DayOfWeek.Value__

# $items[0] = 10
if ($day -ge 1 -and $day -le 5)
{

    $date = Get-Date

    if ($date.Hour -ge 8 -and $date.Hour -lt 17)
    {
        if ($items[0] -gt 0)
        {
            $voice = New-Object -Com sapi.spvoice
            $voice.Rate = 1
            $voice.volume = 100

            Do {
                Start-Sleep -s 1
                $Counter = Get-Date
            } 
            Until ($Counter.Second/15 -is [int])

            if ($items[0] -gt 1)
            {
                [void]$voice.Speak("New Ticket.")
            }
            else
            {
                [void]$voice.Speak("New Ticket.")
            }

        }
    }
}
Write-Output $items.Count
```

The SQL component I have no issues with and definitely works correctly when run, but I have no experience with PowerShell scripting so can someone please assist?

Comment: If you are just interested in the count value of your query, you should probably use $items.Count instead of $items[0].

Comment: Have you tried hoisting and re-using the Com object? Maybe run the script and look in `$Errors` for any hidden problems (don't forget to do a `$Error.Clear()` before running to clean the slate)?

Comment: I've just changed all instances of $items[0] to $items.Count and removed the COUNT from my SQL query so all results display. The PS script is now counting each row I would assume. It does seem to be working... is this an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1):

`$Items.count` is going to give you the number of records in your result set. Technically these are [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) objects and `$Items` is a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx). If you are getting multiple rows back, you need to determine WHICH row you want to show.

Basically the way to would query the returned `DataTable` is:

```
($Items[x]).Column
```

Where `x` is the 0-indexed row you want to return and `Column` is the name of the column you want to return.  So if you want the `ItemCount` column from the second row you would use:

```
($Items[1]).ItemCount
```